# Java-mongodb driver for Java1.2 or Java1.5

Tags: java, mongodb, database

Hi..
In my project i'm using MongoDB and Java. For that i have download java-mongo driver mongo-2.10.1.jar.

Now my problem is, JRE restriction.
 In my project we are using Java1.2 for particular packages and Java1.5 for others. I'm not sure about all the code in mongo-2.10.1 using Java1.2 at max java1.5.

Can any one suggest me which version of java-mongo driver uses java1.2 as max java1.5

Thanks

Comment: You mean you are really using the ancient Java version 1.2, a Java version from 1998, in a production environment? Why? MongoDB, like almost all other current Java software, does not support Java 1.2.

Comment: Exactly clients are still using java1.2 in production env. In java code also we are using java1.2 and java1.5. Any of the monog-java driver release support java1.5(but not beyond that)..??

Comment: Oracle/Sun hasn't given free support supported Java 5.0 for more than five years, you must have more resources than they do :P

Comment: Java 1.2 windows client was developed for Windows 95.  Are they still using that too?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution in your situation is to use a proxy or gateway service.

This way you Java 1.2 client can contact a Java 7 service which talks to the database.  I suggest you do this anyway to cache and centralise you service.  Passing too much logic to such old, under powered client is a bad idea. IMHO.

Comment: My problem was solved..but the thing you have mention was pretty new for me..can you please provide any link or material to get some more details about what you are telling above..

Comment: @SuseendranP Do you mean on how one process talks to another?  There are many ways to do this but the simplest is likely to be using RMI.  You Java 1.2 process calls a method in a Java 5.0 process which does the actual call to MongoDB. Ideally you wouldn't use Java 5.0 or Java 6, but Java 7 since this is the only version currently supported (for free)

Comment: Thanks..i'll see who to talk j1.2 to j1.7 using RMI as well some more methods..my prob was solved after using j1.5 for mongodb-driver..Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB Java driver supports Java 1.5 and above only.  The versions of the Java driver from next year onwards will only support Java 1.6 and above.  Peter's answer is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks..i have extracted the source code and removed annotations in that and i'm using it in java1.5..it was working good..